# What does the exec.skip does in maven command

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

What does the exec.skip does in maven command -

```
mvn clean install -Dexec.skip=true
```

Website http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#skip says:

```
Skip the execution. Starting with version 1.4.0 the former name skip has been changed into exec.skip
```

But what execute it skips?

Comment: If you have configured an execution in exec-maven-plugin it will skip. It will not the execution of the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you read in documentation of exec-maven-plugin this properyt only skip execute of this plugin.

Of course if you dont have correct exec-maven-lugin configuration in your project - `exec.skip` does nothing.